# Wordpress: Reescrever linha de código

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso reescrever uma linha de um Plugin no Wordpress utilizando o functions.php, tentei utilizar o add_filter porem não funciona.

Basicamente eu preciso fazer assim, este é um exemplo da linha original:

```
$return = $post->post_title;
```

Porem, eu preciso através do functions.php deixar ela assim:

```
$return = strtoupper($post->post_title);
```

Existe alguma possibilidade para isso?

Answer (score 1):

seu plugin precisaria estar com um filter no codigo

```
$return = apply_filters('my_plugin_post_title', $post->post_title);
```

e você aplicaria no seu functions.php isto:

```
function uppercase_title( $title ) {
    return strtoupper($title);
}

add_filter( 'my_plugin_post_title', 'uppercase_title');
```